# Customize the scale_x_yearqtr to set specific intervals and end date in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

Given a dataset `df` as follows:

```
structure(list(date = structure(c(14699, 14790, 14882, 14974, 
15064, 15155, 15247, 15339, 15430, 15521, 15613, 15705, 15795, 
15886, 15978, 16070, 16160, 16251, 16343, 16435, 16525, 16616, 
16708, 16800, 16891, 16982, 17074, 17166, 17256, 17347, 17439, 
17531, 17621, 17712, 17804, 17896, 17986, 18077, 18169, 18261, 
18352, 18443), class = "Date"), value = c(12.2, 11.4, 10.9, 10.6, 
10.2, 10.1, 9.9, 9.6, 8.1, 7.9, 7.8, 7.9, 7.9, 7.7, 7.8, 7.8, 
7.5, 7.6, 7.5, 7.4, 7.1, 7.1, 7.1, 7, 6.9, 6.9, 6.8, 6.8, 7, 
7, 7, 6.9, 6.9, 6.9, 6.8, 6.7, 6.4, 6.3, 6.2, 6.1, -6.8, 3.2)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-42L))
```

I have plotted it with code below:

```
df$date <- as.yearqtr(df$date, format = "%Y-%m-%d")
df_m <- melt(df, id.vars='date')

ggplot() +
  geom_line(data = df_m,  aes(x = date, y = value, col = variable), alpha = 0.8, size = 1) +
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 45, hjust = 1)) +
  scale_x_yearqtr(format = "%YQ%q", breaks = df$date, n = 12, expand = c(0, 0))
```

Out:

[image]

Now I need the date labels is plotted quarterly by interval of `2` and end with `2020-Q2`, which means `2010-Q2, 2010-Q4, 2011-Q2, 2011-Q4, ..., 2020-Q2`.

How could I mofify the code above to realize this? Thanks.

Comment: You could select every second 'date' as `breaks`: `d$qtr[c(FALSE, TRUE)]`. Side note: because 'df' already is in a long format, there is no need for `melt`.

Comment: Do you mean by using `scale_x_yearqtr(format = "%YQ%q", breaks = df$qtr[c(FALSE, TRUE)], n = 12, expand = c(0, 0))`?

Comment: I tested, it seems not working.

Comment: I tested on your data and it worked. Note that I created a _new variable_ for the quarters, `df$qtr`, when I tried the code. Perhaps you have another name on the quarters, `df$date`? If so, you should of course modify the code accordingly. Sorry for the confusion. ;)

Comment: Yeah, it works, thanks, if you want please put your solution on the answer part.

Comment: Feel free to write up an answer. Cheers